# Properties of Deformation Retraction

Tags: homotopy-theory

Suppose $Z$ deformation retracts onto a point $z \in Z$, i.e. the constant map $c_z: Z \rightarrow Z$ is homotopic to $id_Z$, where the homotopy is not necessarily relative to $\{z\}$.

Let $H$ be the homotopy from $c_z$ to $id_Z$.

I would like to show that given an open neighbourhood $U$ of $z$, I can choose an open neighbourhood $V$ in $U$ of $z$ such that the inclusion of $V$ into $U$ is homotopic to $c_z$ restricted to $V$ relative to $\{z\}$.

In the case where $H$ is a strong deformation retract and $Z$ is compact, this is straightforward: since $Z-U$ is closed, it's preimage under $H(Z,t)$ is closed, so there is some $t < 1$ such that $H(Z,t')$ is contained in $U$ for all $t' > t$. Let $V$ be an open subset of $H(Z,t')$, then let $H'(x,t') = H(x, t+ t'(1-t))$. Then $H'$ is a strong deformation retract of $V$ onto $\{z\}$.

I do not understand how to generalise this. It feels as though taking the path component of $z$ in $U$ may be helpful, but I don't understand how to actually show that this works.

Comment: I don't see why that $H(Z, t)$ being closed implies the existence of such $t < 1$. Can you explain?

Comment: I *think* that the closure of $Z-U$ implies that the set of $t$ in [0,1] such that the image of $Z$ under $H(.,t)$ is not in $U$ is closed. In particular, since $H(.,1) = z$, there is an open ball around 1 such that the preimage of $Z-U$ has empty intersection with the open ball. So, there's some t < 1 for which $H(Z,t')$ is contained in $U$ for all $t' > t$ - is this clear?

Comment: I don't think the first sentence is true. Maybe you need that $Z$ be compact?

Comment: The image of the preimage of $Z\setminus U$ in $Z\times [0, 1]$ under the projection $Z\times [0, 1]\to [0, 1]$ may not be closed if $Z$ is not assumed compact.

Comment: OK, I'll remove my solution attempt; I'm not supposed to be assuming Z compact.

Comment: I think $Z$ globally being contractible to $z_0$ is not enough. The local structure can still be terrible. I'm writing a counter example now.

Comment: I was worried this might be the case too, but this is an exercise I've been set, not something I just believe...

Answer (score 1):

Counter example:

Let $\mathbf{Q}\subseteq \mathbf{R}$ be equiped with the subspace topology. 
Put $Z = \mathbf{Q}\times[0, 1] / \mathbf{Q}\times\{1\}$ and $z_0 = (0, 0)\in Z$.

Now $z_0$ is a deformation retract of $Z$. It's clear that we can first deform $\mathrm{Id}_Z$ to the inclusion of the point $\mathbf{Q}\times\{1\}$ and then to the inclusion of $z_0$.

However, $U = \mathbf{Q}\times [0, 1[$ is a neighbourhood of $z_0$, and that $z_0$ has no neighbourhood $V\subseteq U$ such that the inclusion $V\hookrightarrow U$ is homotopic to $c_{z_0}$.

Comment: I don't understand your notation in the last line, what does [0,1[ mean?

Comment: The half-open interval. People write $[0, 1[$ as well as $[0, 1)$.